# Is it possible to get the first very first line of html at the top of a document JavsScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to grab the very first line of code in a html document via JS (even if this is a comment?).
When we upload html5 banners to a publisher it needs to have the height and width in a comment at the top of the html before the body tag and would be useful if we could use this in the JS.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
function myFunction() {
  var c = document.childNodes;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    store = c[1].textContent.trim();
    console.log(c[0].textContent.trim());
  }
}
```

and the html would just be:

```
<!-- 140x600 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<p>hi</p>
</html>
```

Is this even possible to grab a comment at the very top of a html document in JS?

Cheers

Comment: Do you want the first line or the first tag/comment?

Comment: the very first line of html is comment. Thats all that I was trying to pull in and store for use in some logic.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to fetch this with:

```
document.firstChild
```

Comment: Somehow I got "insert" not "get" but it's pretty clearly "get" in the question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be rather helpful for you (and a more general solution if we are here) to find the first comment in the DOM, not the first line. This will make it work even if you decide at some point to minify your document (making it all a one-liner).

You should use a [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) with a `SHOW_COMMENTS` filter.

```
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
  document.documentElement,
  NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENTS,
  null,
  false
);

let commentData = null;
while (treeWalker.nextNode()){
  // keep only comments
  if (treeWalker.currentNode.nodeType === 8) {
    commentData = treeWalker.currentNode.textContent;
    break;
  }
}
```

This also supports not having your specific comment the very first node in the DOM.

Comment: this works perfect. Really appreciated. I'd not heard of the createTreeWalker method before!

Comment: I am glad you found this helpful!